# Why is no implicit view found, when eta conversion and specifying type parameters does allow an implicit view to be found?

Tags: scala, implicit

The code:

```
object Test {
  import scala.language.implicitConversions

  case class C1() {}
  case class C2() {}

  implicit def c1ToC2(in: C1): C2 = C2()

  def from[A, B](in: A)(implicit f: A => B): B = f(in)

  def fails(): Future[C2] = {
    val future: Future[C1] = Future.successful(C1())
    future.map(from) // this line fails to compile!
  }

  def compiles1(): Future[C2] = {
    val future: Future[C1] = Future.successful(C1())
    future.map(x => from(x))
  }

  def compiles2(): Future[C2] = {
    val future: Future[C1] = Future.successful(C1())
    future.map(from[C1, C2])
  }
}
```

In this example, only the `fails` method fails to compile.  The error message is:

> Error:(23, 16) No implicit view available from A => B.
>       future.map(from)

I'm confused about why no implicit view is found.  Based on the `compiles1` and `compiles2` methods, which both successfully compile, it seems there **is** an implicit view available from A => B.

What is going on here, and why do the two `compilesN` methods work, but `fails` does not?

My background: I'm still learning Scala, so it could easily be the case that I'm missing something pretty obvious.  :)

I'm on Scala 2.11.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler attempts to resolve implicits before eta-expansion of `from` into a function, so the type parameters of `from` are not yet inferred when you call it like this:

```
future.map(from)
```

`compiles2` obviously works because you supply the type parameters on your own. When you call `future.map(from[C1, C2])`, the compiler knows it will need an implicit `C1 => C2`, because that's what you've told it.

With `compiles1`, the difference is a little more subtle, but it stems from the fact that `future.map(from)` and `future.map(x => from(x))` are actually very different things. The former uses eta-expansion, which fails for the aforementioned reasons. With `future.map(x => from(x))`, there is no eta-expansion happening. Instead, you have an anonymous function that simply *calls* `from` instead of eta-expanding it. Therefore, the compiler can infer the type of `x`, which tells us that `x` is a `C1` (in this case), and it can find the implicit conversion `c1ToC2` that satisfies the type parameters of `from` while resolving the implicit and the final return type of the method, `Future[C2]`.